# I'm very confused - can’t get multiplayer to work on Minecraft Java Ed MacOS or PE iOS, please help!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Sorry for the long post, but I’m reaching the end of my tether with this one!
Having spent nearly 3hrs with an Xbox live chat agent, trying to sort this out and getting almost nowhere.

New MC account for my child, (Java Edition MacOS) who previously played only Bedrock Ed on iOS.
I couldn’t figure out how to get friends to play multiplayer with her via her phone (they play PC Java desktop Edition) and then was good that only if we purchased Java desktop of our own (but ours is Mac, not PC) would they be able to play, because Bedrock can’t play Java.
Couldn’t figure out how to transfer her old MC world to new account, so gave up and bought new MC version and started from scratch.
She can’t seem to find her 2 gaming friends to play with.
All settings in her Xbox live account have been selected to allow multiplayer (double checked with an Xbox live chat agent) but still no luck.
Her Xbox live account is still the old one, from when she played Bedrock version. Does it need to be linked to her new desktop MC account in some way? Or does she need a new Xbox live account altogether?
I was under the impression that an Xbox live account was linked to the user’s Microsoft account and enabled them to play several MS games more easily.
She has only managed to add one other friend so far, who appears in her friends list on Xbox live, but we can’t see this friend’s gamer tag at all when we go into MC itself, why?

All very baffling.

Answer (score 2):

Minecraft Java Edition is not at all linked to Minecraft Bedrock Edition. If your child's friends actually play Java Edition then you will need a server to play on if you want to play together. You can search for servers online, there are plenty of server ranking sites with recommendations. They can either join one of those servers, or if they're all together in person one of them can host a LAN world and anyone connected to that network would be able to join it. You can also set up a LAN world with a VPN but that's a bit more advanced. The alternative to that is of course buying your own server.

If her friends are already playing together on a server, you can just ask them for the IP and add that as a server under the multiplayer menu for the right Minecraft version (which is usually the latest release). From there just connect to that server when her friends are playing and they can all play together.

If you opt for buying a server you'll need to give her friends that IP for them to connect to like I mentioned in the last paragraph. If using a LAN world you won't need the IP and it will automatically show up at the bottom of the multiplayer menu for them to connect to.

Comment: Thanks you very much for replying so quickly. It looks like entering the IP addresses for her two friends, could be the best way first, as they all live far apart and from what I can gather, the LAN play is for players within the same house, using the same router, correct? Maybe I’m wrong. One question, if you don’t mind: what is the point of gamer tags on Xbox live accounts?! Do players using them in MC find and invite theirs friends by gamer tag, or by the usernames they use for MC (the one that appears on the play screen)?  Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, unless you feel like setting up a VPN which probably isn't the best way to go here, LAN is for people connected to the same network yes. Gamer tags then are for players of some other Microsoft games. Minecraft Java Edition is just the exception because it wasn't originally owned by Microsoft. They might work for Bedrock Edition but I don't personally own it and can't say for certain. Also, outside of a server players cannot communicate using their Minecraft usernames. They're only used in game. Players find each other either on servers or through some other method like discord or real...

Comment: ...life and and talk there to determine where they wanna play. Hopefully that answers your questions but if not feel free to respond and I'll try to answer any other questions you have :)

Comment: ...life and and talk there to determine where they wanna play. Hopefully that answers your questions but if not feel free to respond and I'll try to answer any other questions you have :) @JessicaInnocenti-Lampen